# Firebase Auth REST - Log in with Microsoft Provider

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory, spark-java

I'm trying to log in users to a Java Web application written in Java Spark framework using firebase Auth REST API [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/). Reason is since I couldn't find a better way to integrate with Firebase from this framework.

I can use VerifyPassword end point to login using email provider. But I want to use the Microsoft provider in firebase Auth Console instead of email.

Is there a way to use Microsoft Authentication through firebase using the REST API?
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is. You are looking for [Sign In With OAuth Credential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential) section in the Firebase Auth REST API documentation.

> You can sign in a user with an `OAuth` credential by issuing an HTTP `POST` request to the Auth `verifyAssertion` endpoint

However, the process won't be pretty straightforward like it is when using Firebase SDKs. You would have to get an access token from Microsoft (or any auth provider) and then pass it in the request body of Firebase's REST API.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out. Looks like it will be easier to authenticate directly with Azure AD than use firebase Auth if my goal is to use it just for Authentication

Comment: @PeeBee probably yes, if you only need Microsoft auth and not other Firebase product, that might be a better way.